# getting roots of an equation in complex form

Tags: vb.net, equation

I wrote a code to solve quadratic equations displaying  the  roots as output via a text box,but my program is not able to solve equations that would lead to complex or negative roots.How can I add those function to my program.Here is the code I used

Public Class Form1
    Dim a, b, c As Integer

```
Dim x1, x2 As Double
Private Sub Label4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label4.Click

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox4_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles eqnRT1.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    txtA.Text = ""
    txtB.Text = ""
    txtC.Text = ""
    eqnRT1.Text = ""
    eqnRT2.Text = ""




End Sub

Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
    a = Val(txtA.Text)
    b = Val(txtB.Text)
    c = Val(txtC.Text)
    x1 = Math.Round((-b + Math.Sqrt(b ^ 2 - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a), 2)
    x2 = Math.Round((-b - Math.Sqrt(b ^ 2 - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a), 2)
    eqnRT1.Text = x1
    eqnRT2.Text = x2
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: when Δ (=b²-4ac) is negative you can't use `Math.Sqrt` but you know `√(-x) = i√(x)`. So you just need to test for the sign of your Δ and if it's negative calculate the square root of -Δ (which will be positive) and add a "i" in front. Alternatively you could use the [Complex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type and it's `Sqrt` method ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to `System.Numerics` and use the `Complex` structure for your computations.

Try this:

```
Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
    Dim a = New System.Numerics.Complex(Double.Parse(txtA.Text), 0.0)
    Dim b = New System.Numerics.Complex(Double.Parse(txtB.Text), 0.0)
    Dim c = New System.Numerics.Complex(Double.Parse(txtC.Text), 0.0)
    Dim x1 = (-b + System.Numerics.Complex.Sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)
    Dim x2 = (-b - System.Numerics.Complex.Sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)
    eqnRT1.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}+{1:0.00}i", x1.Real, x1.Imaginary)
    eqnRT2.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}+{1:0.00}i", x2.Real, x2.Imaginary)
End Sub
```

It's also a good idea to get into the habit of only rounding for display purposes and to keep all of your calculations free of all rounding.

And, it's best to declare variables within the method they are being used if you've not sharing the values within the class.

Comment: how do I add the reference for system.Numerics ,when I tried running it,it gave a compiler error

Comment: I have been able to add the reference from project tool bar

Comment: Yes, sorry - I should have been more clear. You have to add a reference to the `System.Numerics.dll` assembly.